# Create table in DB2 throws BOOLEAN data type is not supported error. Any idea how to resolve this?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

```
CREATE TABLE AR.Sample_tableM
(
   spring_profiles_active   VARCHAR (100),
   isActive                 BOOLEAN
);
```

> ```
>  Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [428H2] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664]
>  SQL20441N  A "BOOLEAN" data type is not supported in the context where
>  it is being used.
> ```

Comment: . . What part of the error message do you not understand?  Use a `char(1)` or `tinyint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BOOLEAN datatype for a *column* is supported in Db2-LUW since Version 11.1.

Earlier/older Db2-LUW versions did not support this column-datatype, so that may explain your SQL20441N symptom.

Earlier versions supported BOOLEAN for other purposes including parameter-passing, but it was not a column datatype as it is with today's versions.